# Need to create a column with values from one of 3 other columns

Tags: sql

I'm writing a query for a view that pulls 4 specific fields and I need to create a 5th field based on a combination of data from the 4 fields.

More specifically my fields are:
Task1 Complete Date
Task2 Complete Date
Task3 Complete Date
Target Task

I want to create a field called Target Task Complete Date. If the Target Task value = Task1, then it pulls the date from Task1 Complete Date for that record. If the value is Task2, then it pulls the date from the Task2 field, etc.

I have been trying to search for an answer but I don't even know how to phrase what I want in a quick search format. :)

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: Hint:  `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @Gordon for giving me the hint that sent me in the right direction. I came up with this:

'''''

```
Case  
        When Target_Task = 'Task1' then Task1Actual  
        When Target_Task = 'Task2' then Task2Actual  
        When Target_Task = 'Task3' then Task3Actual  
      End as TARGET_TASK_ACTUAL
```

''''''